# Get parameter values out of the QR code URL

Tags: java, eclipse, parameters, qr-code, birt

I have troubles with passing parameter into the QR code URL. When I put the asset number value into the parameter eg. 1004,1005 the URL ending looks like this: ...assetnum=1004,1005 (which is perfectly correct). On my report I want to generate two QR codes - in this case two seperate QR codes...one with assetnum=1004 and the second with assetnum=1005.
I appreciate all the responses.

var link = "https://quickchart.io/qr?text=test%2Fmaximo%2Fui%2Fmaximo.jsp%3Fevent%3Dloadapp%26value%3Dmxkcreatesrm%26additionalevent%3Dinsert%26additionaleventvalue%3Dassetnum="1004,1005"&size=200";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple scripted data set which is based on the array result of xxx.split(","). The data set should return one string for each item in the CSV string.
Then you can use a list or table to output a QR code for each item.

You'll need a two variables: one to store the array and another one to store the current index.